# Update Cell Value in Filtered Sheet Via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, offset, autofilter

I am trying to update column value of filtered data in excel via VBA

I wrote a small macro, which do filter on below table.

[image]

After running macro to filter the sheet, I see below

[image]

Now what I want to do is, I want to update Location value of filtered data. I am trying by using below:

`Range("E100000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(1,0).value ="Abc"`

this set value always at A2 cell which is not part of filtered data.
Need help on how to set /update value one by one in column E for filtered data.

Thanks in Advance!
Vikas

```
here is my code:


Sub Macro3()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TempSheet")
weeklyCommCount = InputBox"Enter Weekly
Communication Count (in number)")
repeateDate = CDate(InputBox"Enter Planning Start
Date ('DD-MMM-YY')", "CHR Planning", "01-Apr-24"))
For i = 1 To 40
For j = 1 To weeklyCommCount
'this is working when sheet is not filtered
Range("E100000").End(xUp). Offset(1, 0). Value = repeate Date
"not working setting alads a Ariying below whic is
Range("E100000").SpecialCells(x|Cel|TypeVisible). Offs
et(1, 0). Value = repeateDate
Next
repeateDate = repeateDate + 7
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you use `.Offset`? It moves the range one row down - which might be hidden by the filter.

Comment: From that part of the code it is not seen what is the problem. Could you show your small macro?

Comment: Code added. and Offset is used to set value one by one next cell in same column.

Comment: Do you want to add new values after the last visible row, or after the whole table? Or replace existing ones. A source data table and an expected result table would be 
helpful. **Sidenote**: If you have filtered rows in the table (hidden) then that command results in an error. Some other approach is needed.

Comment: Basically I want to add location to 1st image's last column one by one after filter

Answer (score 1):

### Filter/Replace Data

[image]

**The Calling Procedure**

```vb
Sub FilterReplaceData()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    FilterListSingleCriteria ws, "A4", 4, "M"
    
    ReplaceFilteredColumnValues ws, 5, ws.Range("A2").Value
    
End Sub
```

**The Called (Helper) Procedures**

```vb
Sub FilterListSingleCriteria( _
        ws As Worksheet, _
        FirstListCellAddress As String, _
        FilterColumnIndex As Long, _
        FilterCriteriaString As String)
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    RefCurrentRegion(ws.Range(FirstListCellAddress)) _
        .AutoFilter FilterColumnIndex, FilterCriteriaString
End Sub
```

```vb
Sub ReplaceFilteredColumnValues( _
        ws As Worksheet, _
        ColumnIndex As Long, _
        Replacement As Variant)
    
    If Not ws.FilterMode Then
        MsgBox "No filtered data found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not ws.AutoFilterMode Then
        MsgBox "No autofiltered data found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim rg As Range
    
    With ws.AutoFilter.Range
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
            On Error Resume Next
                Set rg = Intersect(.Cells, .Columns(ColumnIndex)) _
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    End With
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No filtered rows found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' The same value in all filtered cells.
    rg.Value = Replacement
        
    ' Use something like the following with your new 'Date' requirement 
    ' instead of the previous line.
        
'    If Not IsDate(Replacement) Then
'        MsgBox "The replacement is not a date!", vbExclamation
'        Exit Sub
'    End If
'
'    Dim cell As Range
'
'    For Each cell In rg.Cells
'        cell.Value = Replacement
'        Replacement = Replacement + 7
'    Next cell
        
End Sub
```

```vb
Function RefCurrentRegion( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    With FirstCell.Cells(1).CurrentRegion
        Set RefCurrentRegion = FirstCell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count _
            - FirstCell.Row, .Column + .Columns.Count - FirstCell.Column)
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

The input box will preserve the text for the next input.

```
Sub ins_rows()

defaultx = "Type in text"
For i = 2 To UsedRange.Rows.Count
  If Rows(i).Hidden = False Then
     Cells(i, 5) = InputBox("Text to insert:", , defaultx)
     defaultx = Cells(i, 5)
  End If
  

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this is working.. :).. but i have 18,000 rows and this for loop will continue 18,000 time with another 365*40 for loop.. any other short method pls?

Comment: Your question was about one-by-one this is the reason. If you want the same in all cells then `Cells(i,5)="Replace text"`